# Invalidate another users session variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm thinking of a situation where an administrator makes some changes to another user in the system that happens to be logged in.  Is there any programatic way to invalidate that specific users session variables and force them to be repopulated?

Use Case

1. Admin Edits Bobs preferences
2. Business Logic clears bobs preferences stored in session
3. Preferences saved to database

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to clear the other user's session cookie.

The other way is to create your own [SessionIDManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.isessionidmanager.aspx) (derive from the built-in one). Then when the Validate method is called with the other user's session ID, you can return false.

Comment: I'd love to know how to clear the other user's session cookie.  Could you please give a code example, or a link?